# Google Volley JsonObjectRequest returns 400 bad request error

Tags: http-status-code-400, bad-request, jsonobjectrequest

I had problem with JsonObjectRequest. This is my code:

```
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL, jsonObject,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                try {
                                    VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.toString());
                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("Content-Type:","application/json");
                        return params;
                    }
                };



                ConnectionManager.getInstance(actionBarActivity).add(req);
```

Without overriding getHeaders() i get error 415 Unsupported Media Type.

All result from google sending POST request with JSON shows similar code that i wrote.

Anyone knows why my code return 400 bad request?

Comment: I solved this problem.
you must change getHeaders() method to getBodyContentType() '@Override
                        public String getBodyContentType() {
                            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                        }'